# Issue with accessing a partition of my ssd

Tags: partitioning, nautilus

Hi I'm very new to Linux. This might be some dumb thing that ive done or some stupid mistake I'm not sure. I've dual booted Windows and Ubuntu by making a partition of my SSD of 1 TB. It is split into 3 partitions one for Windows, one named "new volume" where all my files are stored, and the last one for Ubuntu.

The new volume was accessible through the `files` application even until early morning today and it suddenly stopped working and started showing this error message as shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of errors]

I've tried to be specific to the best of my ability but am unable to convey the issue completely due to my lack of knowledge in the field.

Comment: Did you perhaps boot into Windows and then suspended or hibernated instead of shutting down before booting into Ubuntu? Does the problem go away if you boot into Windows again, then **shut down** and then boot into Ubuntu? See [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/q/145902)